# assigning description to cell excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of numbers (e.g 1,2,3) in one column and a list of associated descriptions (A,B,C) in an another column.
In another spreadsheet, I have a list of the quantity the numbers occurred e.g 1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3 etc.

I want to make a count of how many times the numbers occur (which I can do) but I want the associated description to be shown as well.
How do I link a number to a description e.g 1=A,2=B etc.

Note: the quantity of data is huge.

Comment: Your question is either worded horrendously or you did 0 research before posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
=INDEX(descriptions,MATCH(lookup_value,values,0))
```

or as an example:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))
```

but first sort your ranges for much faster results.